# Conditional GET support for chat RSS feeds?

Tags: support, rss

I'm trying to use one of the [RSS feeds](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) from chat.stackexchange.com in my application.  I'm using the python feedparser package for this.  Feedparser supports a couple of different "conditional get" mechanisms, namely [ETag and Last-Modified headers](http://packages.python.org/feedparser/http-etag.html).

However, it doesn't seem like the RSS feed I'm grabbing has these headers.  My goal is to reduce the load on the SE servers, so I'd like to find some way of doing a low-bandwidth poll/refresh of the RSS feed.

This is my first time working with RSS feeds at this level, so it's possible that there's an alternate mechanism supported by these feeds that I can use.  If someone knows what that mechanism is (or if none exists) I'd appreciate the info.

Comment: Please can you confirm; are you talking about an external feed being *consumed* by chat, or do you mean an external application consuming a feed *from* chat?

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm speaking of an external application consuming a feed from chat.  My application is consuming the feed linked from the words "RSS feeds" in the question.

Comment: Then you should find the header is there now, and behaves appropriately#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the next chat build, chat will support "last-modified" (but not ETag) on both inbound and outbound feeds.

Comment: Going to do a few more sanity checks before I accept, but this is looking good, thanks for the quick response!